# Get list of reference nodes In Maya using Python API

Tags: python, c++, maya, maya-api

I just want to list all the reference nodes on the current Autodesk Maya scene file using python API (only), there is this class called `MFileIO` in C++ API but that to returns the referenced file name not the reference node but there is no such class in Python API.

Please any suggestions regarding this.

Note: I don't want to use MEL or Python commands only through API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Maya's 'ls' command to list all of the reference nodes in the scene:

```
import maya.mel as mm
refNodes = mm.eval('ls -type reference')
```

'refNodes' will contain an array of reference node names.

If you dislike using Maya commands for some reason, you can do it purely through the API as well:

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om
it = om.MItDependencyNodes(om.MFn.kReference)
refNodes = om.MObjectArray()
while not it.isDone():
    refNodes.append(it.thisNode())
    it.next()
```

'refNodes' will be an MObjectArray containing the MObjects for all of the reference nodes in the scene.